# Centreon/Nagios check_http: Use different domain name/url

Tags: monitoring, nagios, centreon

I configured Centreon CES as monitoring-system - now I'm facing the following problem:

There is a host with domain `example.com` which resolves to `123.123.123.123`. This host is not configured by me and shows content if user visits `http://example.com` but `404` if user visits `http://123.123.123.123` .

Well, now Centreon shows `WARNING` of course, because the given domain-name is resolved to the ip - and this returns `404`.

Now I tried to modify the `check_http`-command as follows:

```
$USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$
```

as argument I tried to give

```
ARG1 => -u www.example.com
```

What I thought was that the system combines it to

```
$USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u www.example.com
```

But it does not. What would be the correct way to get the result I want to get?

Answer (score 3):

You want the final command to end up with `-H www.example.com` and `-I $HOSTADDRESS$`.

(`-u` would be for something like `-u /index.php`.)

You should make another command like this:

```
define command {
        command_name    check_http_name
        command_line    $USER1$/check_http -I $HOSTADDRESS$ -H $ARG1$
}
```

Which would then be used in the form `check_http_name!www.example.com` in a service definition.

(You could also omit the `-I` part entirely, as long as your domain name resolves correctly in DNS.)

See `check_http --help` output for details on the difference between `-I` and `-H`.